# PassportJS nodejs request https

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

After inserting ssl in my application nodejs the passportjs used for authentication layer informs that the user is not authenticated in the application after an AJAX POST is performed and the page undergoes a window.location.replace().

I have already looked at the documentation and found no reference to the problem, localhost using hpp I do not have this problem.

Would anyone help?

**app.js**

```
var express           = require('express');
var session           = require('express-session');
var cookieParser      = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser        = require('body-parser');
var logger            = require('morgan');
var path              = require('path');
var fileUpload        = require('express-fileupload');
var https             = require('https');
var fs                = require('fs');
var httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join("key.pem")),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join("cert.pem"))
};
var app               = express();
var expressValidator  = require('express-validator');
var passport          = require('passport');
var flash             = require('connect-flash');

// - Cria rotas
var routes            = require('./routes/index');
var usuarios          = require('./routes/usuario');
var motorista         = require('./routes/motorista');
var login             = require('./routes/login');
var aluno             = require('./routes/aluno');
var contrato          = require('./routes/contrato');
var boleto            = require('./routes/boleto');
var pessoa            = require('./routes/pessoa');

require('./security/autenticacao')(passport);

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "50mb"}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(session({
    secret: 'reis&turlwaysrunning',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
 } ));
app.use(logErrors);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.login = req.user;
    next();
});
app.use(fileUpload());
// Atriui rotas
app.use('/home', routes);
app.use('/usuarios', usuarios);
app.use('/alunos', aluno);
app.use('/motoristas', motorista);
app.use('/contratos', contrato);
app.use('/login', login);
app.use('/boletos', boleto);
app.use('/pessoas', pessoa);

https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(8080);

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 21108);
app.listen(app.get('port')); 


function logErrors (err, req, res, next) {
    console.error('Troxa: ' + err.stack)
    next(err)
  }


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: after adding `app.enable("trust proxy");` retry and let me know if any error u facing?
also, in your case, remove this like too `app.listen(app.get('port')); `

Comment: I'll try, thank you

Comment: Same problem occurred